# Generate 8 digit random number in oracle, and the number should be unique

Tags: oracle, plsql

I have written query to generate a random 8 digit nummber and then i am inserting values into a table. The numbers generated should be unique.

Example: Say below is query, this generates random 8 digit number, and then i am inserting it into table temp. Now everytime before inserting into the table how do i need to check if the number generated from below query is alredy in temp table?

Using for loop doesnt seem to be useful as it will cause lag when there are going to be lot of transactions at same time. Any other suggestions like goto, if number is already in table can we use goto and then redirect it to same query until we get a unique value?

Query:

```
select trunc(dbms_random.value(10000000,99999999)) 
into v_customer_nbr  
from dual;
```

Comment: All that has been posted is a program description. However, we need you to [ask a question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). We can't be sure what you want from us. Please [edit] your post to include a valid question that we can answer. Reminder: make sure you know [what is on-topic here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), asking us to write the program for you and suggestions are off-topic.

Comment: Don't directly insert the generated random number directly. Do a select with the generated random number, If the db returns a row, generate another random number do the process again until you get a random number which is not in the table.

Comment: Please let me know if this works : ` SELECT trunc(dbms_random.value(1000000,99999999)) AS random_num FROM dual WHERE "random_num" NOT IN (SELECT randcolumn FROM v_customer_nbr) LIMIT 1`

Comment: Have you considered using a database sequence to generate your numbers ? The output is guaranteed to be schema-unique. However,this will only work reliably if the table column is only ever fed using the sequence. An alternate option is to check uniqueness in an insert/update trigger. I'd favor the sequence solution + a uniqueness constraint on the column, however, as it represents cleaner design anyway imho.

Comment: @jeffrycopps Your solution is unreliable; First, it just fails on duplicate values, the recovery logic needs to be added; second, unless your select is part of an insert statement using the random value, it is also unsafe, since generation and use of candidate values fall into different transactions (ie. the value you generated might already be invalid upon use).

Comment: @collapsar I totally agree. Since, the user had pressed upon a query, came up with that. And yes, recovery logic needs to be added.

Comment: @collapsar - I want the number to be generated in random way instead of in a sequence. As per required process, let us say firstly generated number is 1234, and then next number generated might be 3321, both of which are not in sequence. But i suppose if i use a sequence, then first number would be 1234, and then again, then next number will be 1235.

Answer (score 2):

If you are looking for unique values then you should rather consider using [`SYS_GUID`](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B12037_01/server.101/b10759/functions153.htm) instead. `SYS_GUID` generates and returns a globally unique identifier made up of 16 bytes.